How do I see my private class field values in Firefox debugger?
When the code pauses at a breakpoint, where in devTools are my private class variables displayed? I can see the public ones but not the privates (I mean variables prefixed with #)


class MyClass {

  #myVar;

  constructor() {
    
    this.#myVar = 'foo'
    debugger
  }
  
}


new MyClass()




I get a syntax error when I try to run this, because of the default keyword.

What are you expecting this to refer to outside an instance method? To see instance variables, you need an actual instance.

I fixed the code snippet

.#myVar is not a variable (in a scope), it's a property of an object

WHen you're stopped in the debugger, you can see this in the Scopes > MyClass section of the sidebar. Expanding it shows the private property #myVar: "foo".

More generally, if you're not in a method of the class when you stop, you'll need a variable that contains a class instance. You can enter the variable name in the console, and its properties will be shown.

Thank you for the visual answer. Unfortunately instead of an arrow next to MyClass to expand, two words are written: "optimized away"

Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31503178/how-get-value-of-variable-that-has-been-optimized-out
